# Android - set random button image clickable

Tags: android, image, button, random

I'm having touble in making my random generated image (which is read as a button) become clickable which leads to each different activity for each different image. So the random images work perfect actually, the only problem it's not clickable Here's my code

```
        final Button imgView = (Button)findViewById(R.id.top1);
        Random rand = new Random();            
        int rndInt = rand.nextInt(4) + 1; 
        String imgName = "img" + rndInt;
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getPackageName());  
        imgView.setBackgroundResource(id);
```

On my layout, I specified the id top1 as a button.
So the above code will look up to my drawable images, which have the names 'img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img3.jpg' , and 'img4.jpg'.

So what I wanna make is something like, when 'img1.jpg' is generated, it becomes clickable and leads to for example: Activity1.java , for 'img2.jpg' the intent goes to 'Activity2.java', etc.

Thanks much in advance. I'm open for any kind of solution :)

**UPDATED:**

Here's the full code of my Main class:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main_x);



            final Button imgView = (Button)findViewById(R.id.top1);
            Random rand = new Random();

            imgView.setOnClickListener(new ActivitySwitch(1,this));
            imgView.setOnClickListener(new ActivitySwitch(2,this));
            imgView.setOnClickListener(new ActivitySwitch(3,this));
            imgView.setOnClickListener(new ActivitySwitch(4,this));

            int rndInt = rand.nextInt(4) + 1; 
            String imgName = "img" + rndInt;
            int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getPackageName());  
            imgView.setBackgroundResource(id);

        }
```

and here the ActivitySwitch class:

```
public class ActivitySwitch implements OnClickListener{
    int imageNo;
    Context context;
    public ActivitySwitch(int imageNo,Context context) {
        super();
        this.context=context;
        this.imageNo = imageNo;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent it=new Intent();
        if(imageNo==1)
        {
         it.setClass(context, ProjektAID.class);
        }
        else if (imageNo==2)
        {
         it.setClass(context, ProjektADH.class);
        }
        else if (imageNo==3)
        {
         it.setClass(context, ProjektBOS.class);
        }
        else if (imageNo==4)
        {
         it.setClass(context, ProjektBROT.class);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you added an OnClickListener to your ImageView?

Comment: well my friend you also need to start activity. i doing some changes in my answer plz see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way: create a new class

```
class ActivitySwitch implements OnClickListener{
    int imageNo;
    Activity context
    public ActivitySwitch(int imageNo,Context context) {
        super();
        this.context=(Activity)context;
        this.imageNo = imageNo;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent it=new Intent();
        if(imageNo==1){
         it.setClass(context, Activity1.class);
            }
            else{
            .......
            }
            startActivityForResult(it,any_integer_value);




    }

}
```

And then in the `Activity` set:

```
imgView.setOnClickListener(new ActivitySwitcher(randInt,this);
```

Comment: Hi there, so I've made the ActivityClass like you mentioned above and then on the Main class I've added this: imgView.setOnClickListener(new ActivitySwitch(1,this)); but still the button can't be clicked.. any solution? :(

Comment: plz paste your code for main activity and ActivitySwitch class

Comment: why u r setting so many onclickListener it will just overwritten by last one. just set only one that i suggested in you answer. it will complete your requirement

Comment: because when I write: imgView.setOnClickListener(new ActivitySwitcher(rndInt,this); it gives me an error with the 'rndInt' . what should I change actually on with the onClickListener?

Comment: rndInt cannot be resolved to a variable, btw on the ActivitySwitch Class when I change the 'any_integer_value' for example with '1', it gives me also an error 'The method startActivityForResult(Intent, int) is undefined for the type ActivitySwitch

Comment: then setOnClickListener after you have declared and got rndInt

Comment: ah sorry for being a n00b, yes it works for the rndInt, how about the error I got on startActivityForResult ?

Comment: oh sorry use it like context.startActivityForResult(it,any_integer_value); if it answer your question plz accept it

Comment: So I used this; instead: if(imageNo==1)
        {
         it.setClass(context, ProjektAID.class);
         context.startActivity(it); works perfectly! THX :)
        }

Answer (score 0):

if this is a button, simple implement the function of onclicklistener of button and call the respective activity from text it gets... ping me if u didn't understand..